# Following the output of the dmesg command

Tags: linux, unix, command, watch, tail

I found a solution for tracking the output of the dmesg command in realtime. The solution is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95842/how-can-i-see-dmesg-output-as-it-changeshttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95842/how-can-i-see-dmesg-output-as-it-changes).

```
watch -n 0.1 "dmesg | tail -n $((LINES-6))"
```

It works. But I want to understand why $((LINES-6)) works correctly instead of $LINES.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure $LINES don't work? I'm seeing its working.

Comment: I compared the two results between the "watch -n 0.1 "dmesg | tail -n $LINES"" and "dmesg" commands on Ubuntu. The $LINES one loses the last 6 lines of output.

Comment: I just checked the case plugging a USB into a PC.

Answer (score 9):

dmesg already has this feature. You can use this:

```
dmesg -w
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(($LINE - 6))` substract 6 to `$LINE`'s value and return the result.

Edit:

when using bash (and proabably other shell)

```
   LINES  Used by the select compound  command  to  determine  the  column
          length  for  printing selection lists.  Automatically set if the
          checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive  shell  upon
          receipt of a SIGWINCH.
```

in short, LINES is provided by you `xterm` or `putty` to give LINES and COLUMN number.

Comment: Could you tell me where the $LINE's value comes from? I cannot find information about it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand why $((LINES-6)) works correctly instead of
>   $LINES.

The reason has two parts.

1. `watch` displays a header followed by a blank line, therefore you need to subtract 2 from the number of screen lines available (or use the `-t` option to turn off the header).
2. Some lines of `dmesg` output are longer than the screen width and thus occupy more than one screen line. Since `tail -n` doesn't account for that but rather counts logical lines regardless of their length, it can deliver more lines on screen than asked for, and `watch` displays only the first screenfull of them, losing the rest (4 in your test case). To remedy that, you can wrap the `dmesg` lines to fit in the screen width before feeding them to `tail -n`, for example:

   ```
   watch "dmesg | fold -w$COLUMNS | tail -n$((LINES-2))"
   ```